# nodejs+apache+ react axios stalled or pending

Tags: reactjs, node.js, apache, axios, proxypass

My head is broken.
Have a site with nodejs at backend behind apache.
Some times from react app I see in chrome dev console connections to backend in stalled state or in pending state. after ten or more seconds this connection return 502 error.

apache proxypass config is

`ProxyPass /node2023/ http://192.168.0.9:4005/ #retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=On proxyPassReverse /node2023/ http://192.168.0.9:4005/`

now config is

`ProxyPass /node2023/ http://192.168.0.9:4005/  proxyPassReverse /node2023/ http://192.168.0.9:4005/`

Waiting for errors )

Do not understand why i have pending or stalled state of query to server.

I try to restart apache - no effect
If i restart nodejs app - one hour work fine.